# ekf frame vs topic - remapping issue

Tags: navigation, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
When I override the frame it also overrides the topic.

   ekf publishes on  "/robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined" but if I change the frame as follows:
        <param name="output_frame" value="odom"/>
    then if publilshes under topic:
        "/robot_pose_ekf/odom"

    I thought they where separate setting the topic override via a remap.
    
    Is this correct.  I am still  relativity new to ROS so maybe I have something else set wrong.
    
     <!-- no cammer or scanner used just wheel and imu -->
      <node pkg="robot_pose_ekf" type="robot_pose_ekf" name="robot_pose_ekf">
        <param name="freq" value="10.0"/>
        <param name="sensor_timeout" value="1.0"/>
        <param name="odom_used" value="true"/>
        <param name="vo_used" value="false"/>
        <param name="imu_used" value="true"/>
        <param name="debug" value="false"/>
        <param name="self_diagnose" value="false"/>
        <remap from="imu_data" to="/rrbot/imu_data"/>
        <param name="output_frame" value="odom"/>
      </node>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187459/ekf-frame-vs-topic---remapping-issue/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2014-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The "frame" orresponds to a link (reference frame) in your robot, not the output topic of the node. To remap, use the `<remap>` tag.

**Update:** After your clarification, I suggest renaming the frame and output topic with the `output_frame` parameter and then using `remap` change the topic back to `odom_combined`:

```
  <node pkg="robot_pose_ekf" type="robot_pose_ekf" name="robot_pose_ekf">
    <param name="freq" value="10.0"/>
    <param name="sensor_timeout" value="1.0"/>
    <param name="odom_used" value="true"/>
    <param name="vo_used" value="false"/>
    <param name="imu_used" value="true"/>
    <param name="debug" value="false"/>
    <param name="self_diagnose" value="false"/>
    <remap from="imu_data" to="/rrbot/imu_data"/>
    <param name="output_frame" value="odom"/>
    <remap from="odom" to="odom_combined"/>
  </node>
```

To see how exactly the parameter is used, have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/b384cac812381a9313d7cdc9be9eb272c4fccb38/robot_pose_ekf/src/odom_estimation_node.cpp#L89-L95).

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2014-07-22**:
Maybe I was not clear when I override the frame it overrides both the frame and the topic.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-24**:
Ah, ok, I missed that. Then maybe use remap to get the original output topic while having the frame changed? The way the node interprets the `output_frame` parameter is completetly up to its implementation, so to know what exactly it does maybe have a look at the code.

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2014-07-24**:
I accept this as a work around however I disagree with having to go to source to find out how to interface works with a documented service nor a questionable  use concerning frames and topics.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-25**:
My point only was that it is quite easy to look up in the source what is happening exactly if something is not behaving the way you want it to. Of course better documentation is always preferrable. Please feel free to update the wiki documentation with a better explanation of the parameters.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-25**:
And while remapping is something that works the same for all nodes, there is no convention about how a parameter with the suffix "_frame" is supposed to behave. That is completely up to the node implementor to decide.